# javascript function stops after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good Afternoon,

I have got two functions, one in ajax another one in js as below:

```
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list1').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list1').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list1').html(response.news);
                var audio = new Audio('ding.mp3');
            audio.play();
            }
        });

    }

    //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,2000);
</script>
<script>
    function reblink() {
        $.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){
           eval(blink('.blink'););
        });
</script>
```

now `reblink` function stops right after I call ajax function. Again it does starts when I physically refresh page. What I want to achieve is to start this function after my each call of the ajax function.

I was trying to merging them 2 functions by placing:

```
$.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){
    eval(blink('.blink'););
```

In `if(response.update==true){ }` however it does than stop ajax from functioning.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
So after changes mentioned in comments code is now looking like below:

```
                <script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check4(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#last-orders').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {   /* update counter */
        $('#last-orders').data('counter',response.current);
        /* check if with response we got a new update */
        if(response.update==true){
            $('#last-orders').html(response.news4);
            var audio = new Audio('ding.mp3');
        audio.play();
        reblink() // call reblink here to execute
        }
    });
    }
    //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check4,2000);
</script>
```

**reblink**

```
<script>
function reblink() {
    $.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){
       eval(blink('.blink'));
    });
    }
</script>
```

and function that actually do the blink effect

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
function blink(selector){
$(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        blink(this);
    });
});
}

blink('.blink');

});//]]> 

</script>
```

And after all of those stil ajax call do stop blinking.

Comment: Whoa, what's with `eval`

Comment: hmm? sorry Im not guru I have found this code on someone elses problem in stackoverflow, tryied didnt work.:)

Comment: `eval()` expects a string. what does this `blink()` function return? and what's the extra `;` in there?  that's a flat-out syntax error and will kill the entire script block.

Comment: Pardon, Eval call to this `<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
function blink(selector){
$(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        blink(this);
    });
});
}
    
blink('.blink');

});//]]> 

</script>` so blink function does actuall fading in and out div

Comment: eval expects a string.  blink doesn't return one.

Comment: Help yourself by looking at the errors thrown in browser console. There are important clues there

Comment: Well id does infor me about error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`  in line 36 `$.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){`

Answer (score 0):

This script here has an error in its syntax.

```
<script>
    function reblink() {
        $.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){
           eval(blink('.blink');); // the (;) is the error  
        });
    //} this closing bracket for the function here is missing
</script>
```

And here is the correct syntax below.

```
<script>
    function reblink() {
        $.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){
           eval(blink('.blink'));
        });
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I can see there in your code that you are not calling `reblink()` function. And you mentioned also there that you want to call `reblink()` after `ajax`, you should put `reblink()` inside in your `.done({});` portion of your ajax like this.

```
.done(function( response ) {   /* update counter */
            $('#message-list1').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list1').html(response.news);
                var audio = new Audio('ding.mp3');
            audio.play();
            reblink() // call reblink here to execute
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok I have replaced this script thanks, however it does still stop when I call ajax function and working again only on normal refresh of the page.

Comment: Above, 1: wasnt a part of my question, 2. Did not resolved issue witj javascript stopping after ajax call so far

Comment: and you only need one opening and closing tag of `<script></script>`

Comment: Jus updated top post after changes. Blink effect is still stopping right after ajax call

Comment: what is blink() by the way?

Comment: Well blink is the function that I have listed above that apply fade in and out effect to the specified class.

Comment: I think the script is working fine. Try to `alert()` every event first before using your code. Try to put an `alert()` function in your reblink function, if it alerts every n seconds, then the script is working, if it don't, the problem is in your logic.

Comment: So I have add `alert()` to the `$(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){` and it does alert me every x time. so script it does working.

As you know my ajax code is refreshing data from mysql without reloading the page is this not to do with this? or can I not call blink function on the end of ajax data refresh?

Comment: have you tried to `alert(response)` from .done() argument?

Comment: So this every 2 seconds return `[object Object]` only

Comment: I mean can you get the expected return? ^_^

Comment: I dont think I get that, alert() in .done() function return me nothing empty alert prompt window.?

Comment: Yeah. if you get nothing, therefore it is in your algorithm that is wrong.

Comment: Well yes I do get that there is something wrong, otherwise I would not create this subject there. But I cant work out why it does stops.

Comment: can you mail me your whole code? below yellow at gee ma il dot com

Comment: I have just mail you with all files in case

Comment: one last thing. I may need to know what is the data you want from the database.

Comment: DO you want me to send you a sample of sql table? Mailed already